# VBA - Excel: Mention a Range equal to one given with less one row

Tags: vba, excel, range

So I have a given function which is recieves a range (which is always size (X,1) - meaning it is a column) as argument, something like:

> Function myfunction (byref myrange as Range) as Double
>
> ...
>
> myfunction = stuff
>
> End Function.

Somewhere within that function I need to refer to "myrange of size (X-1,1)".

This is I want to call function that should receive as argument the same range of myrange but instead of being say, B10:B15 I want to pass it B10:B14

And I have no idea how to do it...

Can you help me?
Thanks,

Rui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Resize` method:

```
Function myfunction (ByVal myrange as Range) as Double
    Set myrange = myrange.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)
```

**Important note**: I've changed your prototype to `ByVal` as I'm modifying `myrange`.